# Can not connect to internet on Ubuntu VMWare virtual machine

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware

I am trying to connect to the internet on this virtual machine so i can finish my homework problems but I cant seem to connect.  I have tried many troubleshooting options but cant figure it out.  When i use the command `ifconfig -a` I get this as my output

```
Command 'ifconfig' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install net-tools
```

and when i try to install it, it fails because i am not connected to the internet.
Here is what happens when i run `sudo lshw -class network`  as well

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82545EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: ens32
       version: 01
       serial: 00:0c:29:e9:22:90
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm pcix bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical logical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000 driverversion=7.3.21-k8-NAPI duplex=full latency=0 link=yes mingnt=255 multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:18 memory:fd5c0000-fd5dffff memory:fdff0000-fdffffff ioport:2000(size=64) memory:fd500000-fd50ffff
```

Any kind of help would be amazing! Thank you.

Comment: How is your VM’s network  configured  in VMware?

Comment: @Scott the network connection is bridged and for device status i have both boxes checked for "Connected" and "Connect at power on"

Comment: Does using NAT help?  Possibly your network has a whitelist of MAC addresses allowed to be connected?

Comment: @jamesdlin this did work but for some reason my VMNet8 was deleted, so i had to add the network back and use it.  Thank you!